# Filter multiple fields in QGIS Query Builder

Tags: qgis, filter

How do you filter multiple fields in QGIS' Query Builder?

I tried using the following:

```
"COUNTRIES" IN ('Thailand','Singapore') AND "ROAD_CATEGORY" IN ('Gravel Rd.','Asphalt Rd.')
```

...but it returns 0.

Comment: What format is your data stored in?

Comment: Try to use `OR` instead of `AND`.